# .NET: DataAnnotation attributes in general

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

ASP.NET MVC 2 will support validation based on *DataAnnotation* attributes like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I check that a current model state is valid using **only pure .NET** (not using MVC binding, controller methods, etc.)?

Ideally, it would be a single method:

```
bool IsValid(object model);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code sample is from Steve Sanderson's [blog](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/) about [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) (which uses the DataAnnotationsAttribute to validate properties). Basically, you just need to enumerate the attibutes using reflection and check [IsValid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679289.aspx):.

```
internal static class DataAnnotationsValidationRunner
{
    public static IEnumerable<ErrorInfo> GetErrors(object instance)
    {
        return from prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
               from attribute in prop.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
               where !attribute.IsValid(prop.GetValue(instance))
               select new ErrorInfo(prop.Name, attribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty), instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: I basically did my own validation much like how the data validation attributes work on an MVC project and I basically made the same thing.